# Есть задача в цикле сферам (sphere) задать текстуры из img. Почему то текстура задается только последней в цикле сфере

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10, 32, 16 );
var art = [ '' , '' , '' , '' , '']
arr_planet = []
            arr_planet.push(image)
            arr_planet.push(image_1)
            arr_planet.push(image_2)


for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            var now_it = 'it' + i
            var now_mat = 'mat' + i

            now_it = new THREE.Texture( arr_planet[i] );
             arr_planet[i].addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) { now_it.needsUpdate = true; } );

            now_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                color: 0xffffff, 
                specular: 0x050505,
                shininess: 50,
                map:now_it
            } );

            art[i]= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, now_mat );
            art[i].position.x =(dx)
            scene.add( art[i]);
            dx = dx + 25
        }
```

PS: извиняюсь за корявый код

Answer (score 1):

Попытался сохранить код в первоначальном виде. Заменил использование "THREE.Texture" на "THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture". Код рабочий - загрузилось три шарика с тремя разными текстурами.

```
            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 32, 16);
            var art = ['', '', '', '', ''];
            arr_planet = [];
            arr_planet.push("1.jpg");
            arr_planet.push("2.jpg");
            arr_planet.push("3.jpg");


            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                var now_it = 'it' + i; 
                var now_mat = 'mat' + i; 

                //now_it = new THREE.Texture(arr_planet[i]);
                //arr_planet[i].addEventListener('load', function () { now_it.needsUpdate = true; });

                now_it = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(arr_planet[i]);

                now_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    color: 0xffffff,
                    specular: 0x050505,
                    shininess: 50,
                    map: now_it
                });

                art[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, now_mat);
                art[i].position.x = dx;
                scene.add(art[i]);
                dx += 25;
            }
```